Is there any restriction with regard to latitude or climate as to where a "bright night" can happen?
Recently I learned of bright nights, and I wonder what the restrictions here are regarding latitude or climate. Can this phenomenon happen anywhere in the world, or are there restrictions?

One restriction we can anticipate is that the polar nights would be unlikely to produce this phenomenon. Essentially, you're looking at a phosphorescence process; sunlight must break up gas molecules whose recombination then produces the upper-atmosphere glow. Polar nights, with a prolonged period of no sunlight input, are thus not set up to become bright.
